# Concatenate two org.w3c.dom.Document

Tags: java, xml, concatenation, document

I would like to concatenate two org.w3c.dom.Document s, I have something like this:

```
Document finalDocument = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument()
Document document1 = createDocumentOne();
Document document2 = createDocumentTwo();

// This didn't work
changeFileDocument.appendChild(document1);
changeFileDocument.appendChild(document2);
```

The format of the document1 and document2 is something like this:

```
<headerTag>
    <tag1>value</tag1>  
</headerTag>
```

And what I want is, at the end, a Document like this:

```
<headerTag>
    <tag1>valueForDocument1</tag1>  
</headerTag>
<headerTag>
    <tag1>valueForDocument2</tag1>  
</headerTag>
```

I think that you cannot do this, because they should have a common parent. If so, I would like to create that "fake" parent, concatenate the files, but then only recover the List of elements **headerTag**

How can I do this?

Comment: is `headerTag` your root element? if not what is the root element?

Comment: you need a root element to build up proper xml document. If it is not xml kindly mention the markup language upon which it is build. moreover, why dont you convert the org.w3c.Document (s) to respective String files and concatenate them and finally make another org.w3c.Document instance out of it.

Comment: @A4L, the 'headerTag' is the root element of the Documents created by the methods 'createDocument1' and 'createDocument2' and the only thing I want is to concatenate one after another, even if I have to create a root parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right track with creating a new Document, parsing the parts and add their nodes to the new ones.

Your approach failed because you tried to append a whole document to another one which is not possible.

You could try something like this:

```
public org.w3c.dom.Document concatXmlDocuments(String rootElementName, InputStream... xmlInputStreams) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
    DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
    org.w3c.dom.Document result = builder.newDocument();
    org.w3c.dom.Element rootElement = result.createElement(rootElementName);
    result.appendChild(rootElement);
    for(InputStream is : xmlInputStreams) {
        org.w3c.dom.Document document = builder.parse(is);
        org.w3c.dom.Element root = document.getDocumentElement();
        NodeList childNodes = root.getChildNodes();
        for(int i = 0; i < childNodes.getLength(); i++) {
            Node importNode = result.importNode(childNodes.item(i), true);
            rootElement.appendChild(importNode);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

The code above copies all nodes found under the root element of each document. Of course you can choose to selectively copy only the nodes you are interested in. The resulting document will reflect all the nodes from both documents.

**Test**

```
@Test
public void concatXmlDocuments() throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException, TransformerException {
    try (
            InputStream doc1 = new ByteArrayInputStream((
                "<headerTag>\r\n" + 
                "    <tag1>doc1 value</tag1>\r\n" + 
                "</headerTag>").getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            InputStream doc2 = new ByteArrayInputStream((
                "<headerTag>\r\n" + 
                "    <tag1>doc2 value</tag1>\r\n" + 
                "</headerTag>").getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            ByteArrayOutputStream docR = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        ) {

        org.w3c.dom.Document result = concatXmlDocuments("headerTag", doc1, doc2);
        TransformerFactory trf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer tr = trf.newTransformer();
        tr.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(result);
        StreamResult sr = new StreamResult(docR);
        tr.transform(source, sr);
        System.out.print(new String(docR.toByteArray(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<headerTag>
    <tag1>doc1 value</tag1>
    <tag1>doc2 value</tag1>
</headerTag>
```

**EDIT**

> I would like to create that "fake" parent, concatenate the files, but then only recover the List of elements **headerTag**

As you say, create a *fake* parent. Here is how you could do it:

1) Do the concatenation

```
public org.w3c.dom.Document concatXmlDocuments(InputStream... xmlInputStreams) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
    DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
    org.w3c.dom.Document result = builder.newDocument();
    org.w3c.dom.Element rootElement = result.createElement("fake");
    result.appendChild(rootElement);
    for(InputStream is : xmlInputStreams) {
        org.w3c.dom.Document document = builder.parse(is);
        org.w3c.dom.Element subRoot = document.getDocumentElement();
        Node importNode = result.importNode(subRoot, true);
        rootElement.appendChild(importNode);
    }
    return result;
}
```

2) Recover the node list for headerTag

```
public NodeList recoverTheListOfElementsHeaderTag(String xml) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
    NodeList listOfElementsHeaderTag = null;
    DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
    try (InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
        listOfElementsHeaderTag = recoverTheListOfElementsHeaderTag(builder.parse(is));
    }
    return listOfElementsHeaderTag;
}

public NodeList recoverTheListOfElementsHeaderTag(org.w3c.dom.Document doc) {
    org.w3c.dom.Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();
    return root.getChildNodes();
}
```

**Test**

```
@Test
public void concatXmlDocuments() throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException, TransformerException {
    try (
            InputStream doc1 = new ByteArrayInputStream((
                "<headerTag>" + 
                "<tag1>doc1 value</tag1>" + 
                "</headerTag>").getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            InputStream doc2 = new ByteArrayInputStream((
                "<headerTag>" + 
                "<tag1>doc2 value</tag1>" + 
                "</headerTag>").getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

        ) {

        org.w3c.dom.Document result = concatXmlDocuments(doc1, doc2);
        String resultXML = toXML(result);
        System.out.printf("%s%n", resultXML);
        NodeList listOfElementsHeaderTag = null;
        System.out.printf("===================================================%n");
        listOfElementsHeaderTag = recoverTheListOfElementsHeaderTag(resultXML);
        printNodeList(listOfElementsHeaderTag);
        System.out.printf("===================================================%n");
        listOfElementsHeaderTag = recoverTheListOfElementsHeaderTag(result);
        printNodeList(listOfElementsHeaderTag);
    }
}


private String toXML(org.w3c.dom.Document result) throws TransformerFactoryConfigurationError, TransformerConfigurationException, TransformerException, IOException {
    String resultXML = null;
    try (ByteArrayOutputStream docR = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
        TransformerFactory trf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer tr = trf.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(result);
        StreamResult sr = new StreamResult(docR);
        tr.transform(source, sr);
        resultXML = new String(docR.toByteArray(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }
    return resultXML;
}

private void printNodeList(NodeList nodeList) {
    for(int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
        printNode(nodeList.item(i), "");
    }
}

private void printNode(Node node, String startIndent) {
    if(node != null) {
        System.out.printf("%s%s%n", startIndent, node.toString());
        NodeList childNodes = node.getChildNodes();
        for(int i = 0; i < childNodes.getLength(); i++) {
            printNode(childNodes.item(i), startIndent+ "    ");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><fake><headerTag><tag1>doc1 value</tag1></headerTag><headerTag><tag1>doc2 value</tag1></headerTag></fake>
===================================================
[headerTag: null]
    [tag1: null]
        [#text: doc1 value]
[headerTag: null]
    [tag1: null]
        [#text: doc2 value]
===================================================
[headerTag: null]
    [tag1: null]
        [#text: doc1 value]
[headerTag: null]
    [tag1: null]
        [#text: doc2 value]
```

Comment: Hi @A4L, thanks for your comment, but that is not the output I am interested. I am interested in 
`<headerTag>
    <tag1>dic1 value</tag1>  
</headerTag>
<headerTag>
    <tag1>doc2 value</tag1>  
</headerTag>`

Comment: @Manuelarte, OK, then why bother with XML parsing? the output you want is not valid XML, then the root tag appears two times or there is no root tag, so just read both files as text and apply the `+` operator. If you need to parse it afterwards as XML you will need to wrap it in a root tag of which the name is not `headerTag` then you can get the nodes you want using `Document#getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("tag1");`

Comment: @Manuelarte, I've edited my answer, hope it reflects your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

As you say, you need to have a single root node - and you need to import the other documents. For example:

```
Element root = finalDocument.createElement("root");
finalDocument.appendChild(root);
root.appendChild(
    finalDocument.importNode(document1.getDocumentElement(), true));
root.appendChild(
    finalDocument.importNode(document2.getDocumentElement(), true));
```

Comment: And then, I retrieve the element I am interested by using finalDocument.changeFileDocument.getChildNodes() ?? do I?

Comment: @Manuelarte: Well it's entirely unclear what `changeFileDocument` is meant to be, or what you mean by "the element I am interested".

Comment: you create XML document using the methods createDocument1(), createDocument2(). And then, you want to concatenate them into one single document, known as finalDocument. Later on, I want to recover, from the finalDocument, only the nodes. Is it more clear?

Comment: @Manuelarte: only *which* nodes? Your question was about concatenating documents... I've shown you how to do that. What you do with the document afterwards sounds like an entirely different question.

Comment: thanks for answering. Actually, it was part of the question, but it doesn't matter right now, because only concateneting them is in what I was interested in. Thank you

Comment: @Manuelarte: If you only want the `headerTag` nodes, and they're the root nodes of the original documents, why bother concatenating? For future reference, it's worth making sure that each question you ask is for one specific thing - so in this case, I'd view "concatenating two documents" (as per your title) and "finding just the elements I want" as two different questions, which should be asked in two different posts.